# How to add CC to a webform email?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using Drupal 7.

Is it possible to add a CC to a webform email?

I was using

```
function theme_webform_mail_headers($variables) {
  $headers = array(
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/' . phpversion() . ')',
  );
  return $headers;
}
```

changing it with

```
    function MYTHEME_webform_mail_headers($variables) {
      $headers = array(
'CC' => 'ccmeail@domain.com', 'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/'. phpversion() .')',
 );
      return $headers;
    }
```

It does not work, I've cleared all the chaches and it does not add the CC.
How could I add the CC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of a CC:, why not just add the e-mail address on the "E-mails" tab of the webform content?  You can easily send the output of the webform to any number of e-mail addresses.

Comment: One of the receiving email is a component. How can I add a component and an email? If I put %value[email] it does not accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be done in theme, but in a module (business vs presentation logic).

Don't know if it's still relevant, but [this post](http://drupal.org/node/383504#comment-2397880) explains how to mail to several addresses.

Comment: Same question I asked Patrick.

Answer (score 2):

Just posting this for future viewers:

You can add a hook to the theme_webform_mail_headers in your theme's template.php

```
function mytheme_webform_mail_headers($variables) {
    $headers = array(
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/' . phpversion() . ')',
    );

    $headers['cc'] = 'email@example.com';

    return $headers;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually patched webform_reply_to to work with webform-7.x-4.0-rc3 (using patch identified in Issues) and then modified it to create a Cc header field instead of Reply-To.

In order for it to work with multiple email addresses, you need to comment out the validate call in the module.

Also, email type fields won't take multiple addresses, so you need to use a textfield for your cc field on the form and use the token for that field instead of selecting a pre-defined email field.

Works well, though.